# PostgreSQL 12 zero sized wal archive logs issue during recovery

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, recovery, wal

I am having this issue with the PostgreSQL database running using DAS disks. I have enabled Archive logs on the PostgreSQL configuration. When the server crashes I see a lot of zero-sized WAL archive logs getting created as seen in the picture below. What is the recovery process as PostgreSQL complains it is not 16MB in size. So I tried deleting or filling it to 16MB size to do the recovery. It seems to be working fine but is this a correct process to do the recovery. Any insights would be really appreciated.
Have you any of you faced this problem before? I have raised a bug with PostgreSQL as well regarding the same.

PostgreSQL zero-sized WAL logs:

[image: PostgreSQL zero-sized WAL logs]

Comment: Here is the log error during recovery: FATAL: archive file "000000010000000C00000080" has wrong size: 0 instead of 16777216

Comment: What was the log for when the defective WAL file was created?  What is your archive_command?

Comment: # - Archiving -

archive_mode = on               # enables archiving; off, on, or always
                                # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'test ! -f /tmp/data/lvarch/%f && cp %p /tmp/data/lvarch/%f'          # command to use to archive a logfile segment

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran out of disk space.

At any rate, PostgreSQL will bemoan these WAL segments and stop recovering before the first one, which is the right thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I had a lot of space left for archive logs. Disk space is not a problem. Have you seen this problem before?

Comment: No, not really. But my answer should still apply. You should add relevant portions of the log file to the question.

Comment: Thank you again. I have added the error log to the thread. Don't you think it is a bug? I have raised a bug with PostgreSQL, hopefully they will respond soon. It is like PostgreSQL is not crash consistent.